# MIDI editor with ability to export to mp3 or Ogg Vorbis using DosBox-style sound card emulation?

Tags: gratis, audio

I'm looking for a lightweight digital audio workstation (DAW) program built for editing MIDIs and exporting them to a modern compressed format (such as mp3 or Ogg Vorbis) through emulated sound cards similar to what DosBox provides (see https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Sound). Can be any major modern desktop platform (Windows, Mac OS, Linux).

I will be using the program to write music in "tracker module" style - writing notes with a computer keyboard and mouse, no need for physical instrument connectivity. It does not need to support a piano-style "MIDI keyboard", guitar, or drum interface. (therefore, this question is **not** a duplicate of [Cheapest software with MIDI support and sound effects](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/32263/cheapest-software-with-midi-support-and-sound-effects) which specifically requests MIDI keyboard support)

I've already looked into Anvil Studio (https://www.anvilstudio.com/) but it's unclear what it uses to play a MIDI (probably the computer's default "sound font"). It's also unclear what exactly it supports as output formats out of the box other than MID, WAV, and maybe WMA.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to edit MIDI files? You could try RAD (Reality Adlib Tracker)? It's a tracker for DOS/Windows/Mac that emulates OPL2 and OPL3 sound chips.

https://www.3eality.com/productions/reality-adlib-tracker

Comment: Yes. That's the whole point of it. I would use the program to write music.